# Implementing merge sort for an array list of objects in java

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, arraylist, mergesort

I'm looking to implement a merge sort using an array list of objects. Ideally, I would like to have a static method that takes the array list to be sorted and a boolean as parameters. The boolean, if true, would implement merge sort recursively, and if false would implement the sort using just loops rather than recursion.

Here is the car class used for the object data.

```
public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    private Double milesPerGallon;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private Integer year;
    private Double milage;
    private Double initialPrice;

    public Car(Double milesPerGallon, String make, String model, Integer year, Double milage, Double initialPrice) {
       this.milesPerGallon = milesPerGallon;
       this.make = make;
       this.model = model;
       this.year = year;
       this.milage = milage;
       this.initialPrice = initialPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Car o) {
        int result = this.year.compareTo(o.getYear());
        if (result == 0) {
            result = this.make.compareTo(o.getMake());
            if (result == 0) {
                return this.model.compareTo(o.getModel());
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        } else {
            return result;
        }
      }
}
```

I have gotten to recursive part to work as intended but I am having issues with the iterative sort. Here is my method as it stands.

```
public static ArrayList<Car> mergeSort(ArrayList<Car> toSort, boolean recursive){

    // NON - RECURSIVE METHOD
    if(recursive == false){
        int currentSize;
        int leftStart;

        for(currentSize = 1; currentSize <= toSort.size() - 1; currentSize = 2 * currentSize){
            for(leftStart = 0; leftStart < toSort.size() - 1; leftStart += 2 * currentSize){
                int mid = Math.min(leftStart + currentSize - 1, toSort.size() - 1);

                int rightEnd = Math.min(leftStart + 2 * currentSize - 1, toSort.size() - 1);

                merge(toSort, leftStart, mid, rightEnd);
            }
        }
    }

    // RECURSIVE METHOD
    if(recursive == true){

        if(toSort == null){
            return toSort;
        }

        if(toSort.size() > 1){
            int mid = toSort.size() / 2;

            // split left half
            ArrayList<Car> left = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++){
                left.add(toSort.get(i));
            }

            // split right half
            ArrayList<Car> right = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = mid; i < toSort.size(); i++){
                right.add(toSort.get(i));
            }
            mergeSort(left, true);
            mergeSort(right, true);

            int i = 0; // index left
            int j = 0; // index right
            int k = 0; // index whole

            // merge left and right lists
            while(i < left.size() && j < right.size()){
                if(left.get(i).compareTo(right.get(j)) == -1){
                    toSort.set(k, left.get(i));
                    i++;
                }else{
                    toSort.set(k, right.get(j));
                    j++;
                }
                k++;
            }

            // remaining list elements
            while(i < left.size()){
                toSort.set(k, left.get(i));
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            while(j < right.size()){
                toSort.set(k, right.get(j));
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }


    return toSort;
}
```

and here is the method used in the iterative part that is currently not working.

```
public static void merge(ArrayList<Car> toSort, int left, int mid, int right){
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = mid - left + 1;
    int n2 = right- mid;

    // temporary lists
    ArrayList<Car> leftList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Car> rightList = new ArrayList<>();

    // copy data to temporary lists
    for(i = 0; i < n1; i++){
        leftList.set(i, toSort.get(left + i));
    }
    for(j = 0; j < n2; j++){
        rightList.set(j, toSort.get(mid + left + j));
    }

    // merge temporary arrays into toSort
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = mid;
    while(i < n1 && j < n2){
        if(leftList.get(i).compareTo(rightList.get(j)) == -1 || leftList.get(i).compareTo(rightList.get(j)) == 0){
            toSort.set(k, leftList.get(i));
            i++;
        }else{
            toSort.set(k, rightList.get(j));
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i < n1){
        toSort.set(k, leftList.get(i));
        i++;
        k++;
    }
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to implement such algorithm? I found the: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/ and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-merge-sort/ where the iterative approach still needs to make a few recursive calls. The examples there for Java are built for standard arrays, but changing the parameters, declarations, accessing by index and the comparison with standard operators to `compareTo` method calls  shouldn't make a problem. Ping me in comment with @ if you'll still have a problem, I'll try to provide some solution later.

Comment: @itwasntme I have managed to get the recursive function to work based off of the second link you provided me. I attempted to use that same link to get the iterative version to work but I am getting out of bounds exceptions when run. I have edited my code to reflect the progress I have made. I think the issue is converting the syntax from arrays to arraylists, but I am unsure how exactly to fix it. If you have any ideas please let me know. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Side issues that may help dis-entangle things so you can think more clearly about them… `if (recursive == true)` can be reduced to `if (recursive)` & `if (recursive == false)` reduces to `if (! recursive)` (don't compare booleans to true or false). Since you're testing both true and false, and those are the only possible values, you can do `if (recursive) { /* do recursive */ } else { /* do iterative */ }`. Then… why use a boolean instead of just having 2 separate methods? Is it, for example, a homework requirement that you use a boolean? Keep them apart so changing one can't affect the other.